# Creating a form and depending on selections output a link

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to setup a web page where the user can select a website and a format they want to display on said website.

I've done the form, but I also need to output a link when a user selects Google.com as the website and then selects 1000x1000 as the format I want the output to be "Google.com/?demo=1000x1000.

I think the best solution would be if I could store all these formats in a way and when you select "Google.com" as the website and then selects the format I want the link to be this for example: "website.com/?demo=format"

This is the code I've written so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>



    <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option>Choose site</option>
        <option value="#">Google</option>
        <option value="#">Apple</option>
        <option value="#">Amazon</option>
    </select>​
    <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option>Choose format</option>
        <option value="#">Mobile</option>
        <option value="#">Desktop</option>
        <option value="#">Tablet</option>
    </select>​





  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried so we can better help.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated my original post :)

Comment: why is the value `#` and not what you want it to be?

Comment: It's just a placeholder for now since I got stuck.

 Basically what I'm trying to do is to have 2 dropdown menus(or 3 if possible), where one is the "Website" and then "Formats" when the user selects both of these for Example "Apple" + Mobile + 1000x1000" I want the output to be apple.com/?demo=1000x1000

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <select id='site'>
         <option>Choose site</option>
         <option value="#">Google</option>
         <option value="#">Apple</option>
         <option value="#">Amazon</option>
      </select>
      <select id='format' onchange="myFunction()">
         <option>Choose format</option>
         <option value="#">Mobile</option>
         <option value="#">Desktop</option>
         <option value="#">Tablet</option>
      </select>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
            var site = document.getElementById("site");
             var format = document.getElementById("format");

             if(site.selectedIndex == 0) {
                alert('Please choose a site');
                 return 0;
             }

             var location = site[site.selectedIndex].text;
             location += ".com/?demo="
             location += format[format.selectedIndex].text;

             alert(location)
         }

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alot.

 Exactly what I was looking for! Would it be possible to add a submit button that then either makes the link clickable or just redirects after making the selections?


Also - when choosing the format I realized that when I name these in my HTML code I don’t want spaces, so after ”.se/?demo=” I want the format name to be displayed without spaces, would that also be possible in any way?

Comment: you can use ((window.location = location)) for  redirect to selected page

Comment: for remove spaces you can use ((  format[format.selectedIndex].text.trim()  )). trim function will remove all of the spaces!

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code with **required** HTML5 attribute which prevents the form send with default browser notice if the value of input is empty.
The submit button call the form onsubmit event, which can be stopped by `preventDefault()` method and then redirected by `location.href` just like you did.

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); location.href=this.site.value+'?demo='+this.format.value;">
    <select name="site" required>
        <option value="">Choose site</option>
        <option value="https://www.google.com">Google</option>
        <option value="https://www.apple.com">Apple</option>
        <option value="https://www.amazon.com">Amazon</option>
    </select>​
    <select name="format" required>
        <option value="">Choose format</option>
        <option value="1x1">Mobile</option>
        <option value="2x2">Desktop</option>
        <option value="3x3">Tablet</option>
    </select>​
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

After reading your comment, I believe you can benefit from **formaction** attribute which can be set on submit button. This simplifies the code to this (no javascript at all):

```
<form>
    <select name="format" required>
        <option value="">Choose format</option>
        <option value="1x1">Mobile</option>
        <option value="2x2">Desktop</option>
        <option value="3x3">Tablet</option>
    </select>​
    <input type="submit" value="Google" formaction="https://www.google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Apple" formaction="https://www.apple.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Amazon" formaction="https://www.amazon.com">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! The first code you posted was alot better for my needs since I still need the ?demo part. Gonna work on the first snipped you posted to make it look nicer with CSS, thanks alot again!!!

Comment: Hey, thanks again for the help! Was wondering if this was possible to do but in another way, basically what I want to do when someone enters the website is they first select "site" and then "format" I've been trying to do this with images, so it's easier for the users to interact with the website, but it seems like maybe I have to rethink it all for that to be possible?